# Symfony security: Is there an event when a user is authenticated from the session?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

Is there any event when Symfony authenticates a users from the session? `LoginSuccessEvent` seems only to be fired during an interactive login, e.g. when using a login form but not when a new page is loaded for an already logged in user.

**Details:**

I am working on a Symfony 6.1 based project and I followed the instructions in the Symfony docs (e.g. [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) and [here](https://symfony.com/doc/5.2/security/form_login_setup.html)) to build security based on a user class and a login form.

Everything works fine: Access to restricted pages is blocked by the firewall, the user is redirected to the login form where he can login. Once logged in, all pages can be accessed until the login expires.

After submitting the login form `LoginSuccessEvent` is fired. However, when loading a new page using the user from the session, this event is not fired. Is there any other security event for this kind of authentication? None of the events I found in the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#authentication-events) seem to apply to this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the event is executed only once at login. Alternatively, you can create a `kernel.request` event that will be fired on every request. In the event, you can pass the Security component to the constructor arguments and get the current user and perform the necessary actions

```
use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class UserListener
{

    private Security $security;

    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $this->security->getUser();
        if (!$event->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest() and $user instanceof User){
            // do something ...
            dump($user);
        }
    }
}
```

Registering a listener in services.yaml

```
App\EventListener\UserListener:
    tags:
        - {name:  kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request }
```